# AJV nullable type for enum not working in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ajv

I am using schema in below format,

```
  "Status":{
                 "type":"string",
                 "nullable":true,
                 "description":"TBC",
                 "minLength":1,
                 "maxLength":1,
                 "enum":[
                    "Y",
                    "N"
                 ],
                 "example":null
              }
```

When i am passing null value in "Status" then it's throwing error, which basically means the ""nullable":true" is not working for enum, but the same working for any string values.
e.g

```
      "Status":{
                 "type":"string",
                 "nullable":true,
                 "description":"TBC",
                 "minLength":1,
                 "maxLength":1,
                 "example":null
              }
```

Here if i pass null value then it'll validate and accept the null value ("nullable":true working).

Can anyone help me validate nullable enum?

https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#nullable

Answer (score 1):

This is an older unanswered question but I stumbled on it when experiencing the same issue. Figured I'd provide an answer here for anyone else that might encounter this and find this old question.

The linked docs have probably been updated since this question was originally asked, but they now provide details on why this does not work:

> nullable does not extend enum and const
>
> If you use enum or const keywords, "nullable": true would not extend
> the list of allowed values - null value has to be explicitly added to
> enum (and const would fail, unless it is "const": null)
>
> This is different from how nullable is defined in JSON Type
> Definition, where "nullable": true allows null value in addition to
> any data defined by the schema.

```
  "Status":{
             "type":"string",
             "nullable":true,
             "description":"TBC",
             "minLength":1,
             "maxLength":1,
             "enum":[
                "Y",
                "N",
                null
             ],
             "example":null
          }
```

You still need to include `"nullable: true"`. Essentially `enum` and `nullable` are evaluated independently.